# My percentage calculation is showing NULL values using GROUPBY

Tags: mysql, math, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get the percentage of play results using aggregate functions. There are four categories and I am using a `GROUP BY` clause to count the number of instances using `count()`. When I go to calculate the percentage, I get only `NULL` values. I've been trying using all sorts of combinations with the parentheses but nothing seems to work.

```sql
SELECT passResult, count(passResult) AS countPassResult, (count(passResult) / sum(passResult)) * 100 AS pctPassResult
FROM plays
WHERE possessionTeam = 'PIT'
GROUP BY passResult
```

This is my first question posted here so please let me know if I missed any key details.

P.S. I really don't know how to share data but hopefully this adds more context on what I am trying to do.

| passResult | countPassResult | pctPassResult |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 7345 | 60.91 |
| I | 3623 | 30.04 |
| S | 822 | 6.82 |
| IN | 269 | 2.23 |

Comment: post some sample data

Comment: Is it because the type of `passResult` is not a number (INT/DECIMAL) ? Please provide more information.

Comment: @MicFung gives useful recommendation. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43857aaee7843b54d404c658cd61d074

Comment: @MicFung possibly. I guess my question is can I not do math on aggregate functions (count) if the columns aren't numeric? passResult is a TEXT datatype and it just has four possible results ('C', 'I', 'S', 'IN'). I was hoping to do math on the counts.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for putting this together. The last example you show is exactly the problem I'm seeing.

Comment: @Oscar Castro , i don't quite sure if i follow you. what you want is to calculate (total no of 'C', 'I', 'S', 'IN' ) / (total no of rows in plays). Therefore, the `pctPassResult` should be `count(passResult) / (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM plays) * 100 AS pctPassResult`. For `sum(pctPassResult)`, i guess you actually want the total no of rows in plays

Comment: @Oscar Castro ,  I added the SQL in Akina shared fiddle at the bottom, you can take a look